# Collect a type of attributes into an array, only when exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So my Question is, that there is an Object.weight.

I want to find all Objects where user_id is @user.id, then put all the Object.weight
attributes into an array, only where attribute is not nil.

like

```
@o = Object.find.where(:user_id => @user.id)
@a << @o.weight.where(:weight true)
```

And then i would like to list all those from the array, with a ',' separator.

all the best!

Comment: no offense but the "all the best!" gives me the feel of a question paper in an examination hall :)

Comment: was thinkin about what to write there, next time maybe just 'thanks' ;)

Comment: btw never experienced such fast and precise help, this was my first question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.where(:user_id => @user.id).collect(&:weight).compact
```

`collect` fetches all the elements from an Arrays Items and `compact` removes all `nil` objects from the array.

For the view:

```
arr.join(", ")
```

Comment: jvnill's solution of avoid `nil`s is the better one when your date is stored in a databse.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@weights = Record.where(user_id: @user.id).where('weight IS NOT NULL').map(&:weight)
puts @weights.join(',')
```